# How to make these lines visible in Latex?

Tags: margins

I'm new to LateX, I don't know how to set borders like these in LaTeX. Please help me, my paper is due tomorrow. :( [image: This was written in MS Word, I want to make this one again using LaTeX]

Comment: `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` would be very similar (though not exact) to what you show, providing the borders of the LaTeX page fields, including headers, footers, marginpar border, and text border.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{comicsans}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{rulecolor}{LightSteelBlue3}
\newcommand\colorhrule{\makebox[0pt]{\color{rulecolor}\rule{0.95\paperwidth}{0.6pt}}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{title}{%
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot{}{}{\raggedleft\rlap{\quad\thepage}}
}%

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{showframe, nomarginpar, nohead, footskip = 6pt, hmargin=25mm, top=15mm, bottom=20mm}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{title}
  {\color{rulecolor}\smash{\rule[-0.95\paperheight]{0.8pt}{1.05\paperheight}}\hfill\smash{\rule[-0.95\paperheight]{0.8pt}{1.05\paperheight}}}
  \begin{center}
    \colorhrule\medskip\par
    \MakeUppercase{university of nowhere}
    \par\colorhrule
    \vskip12mm
    \MakeUppercase{action potential patterns of a cardiomyocyte}
    \par\vfill
    {\huge\sffamily\bfseries I}
    \par\vskip20mm
    A Research Proposal submitted to the\\
    Department of Mathematics and Physics
    \par\vfill
    in Partial Fulfillment\\
    of the Requirements for the Degree of\\
    Bachelor of Science in Applied Physics
    \par\vskip35mm
    \colorhrule
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]